# If$ \int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx=M$ and $\int _b^c\:f\left(x\right)dx=L$ is it correct to say that $\int _a^c\:3f\left(x\right)dx=3\left(M+L\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration

If $\int _a^b\:f\left(x\right)dx=M$ and $\int _b^c\:f\left(x\right)dx=L$ is it correct to say that $\int _a^c\:3f\left(x\right)dx=3\left(M+L\right)$

I'm a little bit confused, but I suppose it's correct. I've tested simply by replacing things. $a=1, b=2$ and $c=3$ and placed $f(x)$.

$$\int _1^2\:f\left(x\right)dx\:= \frac{3}{2}$$

$$\int _2^3\:f\left(x\right)dx\:= \frac{5}{2}$$

Therefore,

$$\int_1^3\:3f\left(x\right)dx\:= 12f$$

would be equal to:

$$3\left(\frac{3}{\:2}+\frac{5}{2}\right)=\:12$$

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $\int_a^cf = \int_a^bf + \int_b^cf$ always holds as long as each of the individual integrals exist.

Comment: Analytically the equality is okay under necessary conditions. Now taking $f(x)=x$ as you've supposed $\int_1^33f(x)dx=3\int_1^3f(x)dx=3(\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2})=3(\frac{8}{2})=3•4=12$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it can be proved using the properties of definite integrals.

\begin{align}
\int_a^c{3f(x)dx} 
 &= 3\int_a^c{f(x)dx} \\
 &= 3\left(\int_a^b{f(x)dx + \int_b^c{f(x)dx}}\right) \\
 &= 3(M + L) \\
\end{align}